# How Kafka 0.9+ selects a broker to be the offset manager (or group coordinator) for a new consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How does Kafka 0.9+ select a broker to be the offset manager or group coordinator for a new consumer group? Does it keep track of the number of groups managed by each broker and try to load balance, assigning new group to the broker who is managing the least number of groups? Does it take into account the number of consumers in each group so the number of connections to each broker is balanced too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it follows the rule below:

1. Determine the target partition for the group by calculating:

`Math.abs(groupID.hashCode()) % numPartitionsOfGroupMetadataTopic`

By default, `numPartitionsOfGroupMetadataTopic` is the `__consumer_offsets` topic with a default partition count of 50)

2. Find out the leader broker for this partition and specify this broker as the coordinator for this group.

Comment: What is groupMetadataTopic used for? Cannont find any information about it

Comment: It's an internal topic which is used to store the offsets for consumer groups.

Comment: do you mean __consumer_offsets topic?